# Should the young generation size be more than a service's normal heap consumption?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

We have a service, whose process sitting idle, takes a heap memory of 612 MB.

The heap of our service is given a initial and maximum size of 1GB. The young generation, as checked from gc logs, is ~400 MB.

There are a lot of minor GCs.

Is this because the service by default takes more memory than the young generation?

In another bigger host, the young generation size is ~615 MB and there are very less number of minor GCs here. The initial size of heap here is 1 GB and max size is 2 GB. At the time of taking the note, the total size of heap was 1 GB. So with the same total heap size, the young generation size was different.

Wanted to understand these things:

- Can this indeed be the problem?
- Is there a standard practise to keep young generation size more than the heap consumption of the service's process?

Comment: Are you missing any of your performance goals such as a latency or throughput? Otherwise I wouldn't worry/overoptimize too much.

Comment: Yep - There are a lot of CPU spikes. The "frequent" GCs are 1 per second. In the bigger host it's 1 per 10 minutes. The smaller hosts go down after the CPU spikes. That's why.

Comment: You're using a GCed language. The GC needs CPU cycles, so a priori a CPU spike is unexpected. Do you have any application-level measurements, other than CPU utilization, that are an actual problem that needs to be fixed?